# PDFs wont show on web servers but show on local machine

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, server

So im trying to display a random PDF, didnt do any web stuff for a long time so it was a bit of a quick thing. Basicly i genereate a random number, pdfs are named numericaly from 1 and increasing. pdfs are 1-521.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    text-align:center; /*this is for the text above the board*/
}
#memory_board{ /*settings for the background of the board*/
    background:#CCC;
    border:#999 1px solid;
    width:800px;
    height:540px;
    padding:24px;
    margin:0px auto;

}div > div{ /*settings for the rectangles*/
    background: url(tile_bg.jpg) no-repeat center;
    border:#000 1px solid;
    width:71px;
    height:71px;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:64px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}

</style>

<script>


var pdf;


function change(){

    var ttt = Math.floor((Math.random() * 512) + 0);
    pdf = "" + ttt + "." + "pdf";
    console.log(pdf);
    document.getElementById("myIframe").src = pdf;
    document.getElementById("myIframe").contentWindow.location.reload();
}
change();


</script>
</head>

<body>

<h1>SIS 1 RANDOM</h1>

<script>
window.onload = change;
//<iframe id="myIframe" src="1.pdf" height="800" width="600"></iframe>
</script>

<button id="1" onclick="change()">Random</button>
<embed id="myIframe" src="1.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>

</body>

</html>
```

for some reason it wont work on any webservers i put it on. And I have no idea what could be wrong. maybe the file paths are different? Im not sure

The erorrs i get on load on the webserver are such:

```
MemoryGame.html:61 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: "http://pitastrudl.me/downloads/Memory_game_9/1.pdf".

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
    at change (MemoryGame.html:42)
    at MemoryGame.html:45
```

Im guessing the second error is something to me doing wrong, by refreshing the frame before its loaded or something? Im not sure what the first one means though.

Comment: At a guess, you're calling change() before the iframe has been rendered into the page, hence setting the source is failing. Try moving your script to the endof the page (beneath the closing body tag)

Comment: That did get rid of one error, but the "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf: 'link_to_the_pdf'  " still remains.

Comment: I have just opened the link in firefox and it works there. wierd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed

```
 pdf = "" + ttt + "." + "pdf";
```

to

```
 pdf = "" + ttt + "." + "pdf.jpg";
```

and instead of the

```
<embed id="myIframe" src="1.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>
```

used this

```
 <div><img src="yourimg" id="myIframe" ></div>
```